# How to split the response I get from a HTTP request into 2 separate arrays and use them in the subsequent HTTP request in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have extracted several values like 'XYZ_2020-04-20' as part of my first HTTP request from the response like below:
checkboxes__input' id='XYZ_2020-04-20' name='payment[invoices][XYZ][]' type='checkbox' value='2020-04-20'.

I am trying to split the first 20 values (from 'XYZ_2020-04-20' ) into 2 separate values (like 'XYZ' and '2020-04-20') and use both of them (resulting 20 values) in the subsequent HTTP request. Please could you help me how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use two separate extractors and save them as different variables from the start.

Comment: It will be tricky as I get hundreds of values like ABC_Date1, ABC_Date2, ABC_Date3,...XYZ_Date1, XYZ_Date2,...